# What should I do to the entries that have a lot of 0's?

Tags: pandas, data-cleaning, knn, imputation

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/68eVJ.png)

Should I keep these entries as they are and use them for modeling?

I thought of applying KNNImputer, but I still don't know what would that result to.
Should I just drop entries with 0 balance which make up 35% of the data?
Maybe if there's another way to impute this data please do tell.

Comment: Well, it's your choice. What are those zeros? Real values, anomalies? Do you want to take them into account in your model?

Comment: Yes I want to take them into account, and I applied KNNImputer it resulted into a gaussian normal distribution give or take, but does that really help the model to detect if an individual churned or not?

Comment: Welcome to SO. What are you trying to accomplish? As written, your question is poorly formed and it is therefore difficult to provide meaningful help.